# SUBIR IMAGEN CON LARAVEL PROBLEMA!

Tags: laravel, imagen

estoy intentando subir 2 imágenes,pero no me esta capturando las imágenes, como demuestro en la foto, se supone que en

> "img_p_circulacion":{},"img_r_tecnica":{}}

debiera salir el nombre de la imagen dentro de las '{}', pero no aparece, adjunto código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('vehiculos.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" files=”true” >
   {{ csrf_field() }}
      <label>Fecha de vencimiento permiso circulación</label>

    <div class="input-group date col-md-6" id='fechaPermisoCirculacion'>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Fecha" name="fecha_P_circulacion" required/>
         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" name="img_p_circulacion">
    </div>

    <label>Fecha de Vencimiento de la Revisión técnica</label>

    <div class="input-group date col-md-6" id='fechaRevisionTecnica'>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Fecha" name="fecha_R_tecnica" required/>
         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" name="img_r_tecnica" >
    </div>
        <div class="input-group col-md-4">
        <div class="box-header">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Solo una apreciación, no se si tiene algo que ver. Pero las comillas al rededor de `files="true"` no son comillas comunes.

Comment: no es la solucion, pero gracias por avisar, lo tome en cuenta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz probado recibir los archivos de la siguiente forma?

```
$request->file('img_r_tecnica');
$request->file('img_p_circulacion');
```

Y en todo caso para asegurarte de que las imágenes están llegando podrias usar dd de la siguiente forma:

```
dd($request->file('img_r_tecnica'));
```

Comment: excelente amigo gracias!